# How to remove the Google Calendar duplicate events?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, google-account

I have been using Google Calendar for quite a while now. But now I am facing too many duplicate events in my calendar.

Here's what my setup is:

- **Account 1** - Individual google account is given by my organization.
- **Account 2** - Office google account is given as I am an officer.

Now when an event is scheduled by my office, my individual account is invited. But as I am using the office account as well, the same event is displayed twice in my calendar. I cannot hide any of the calendars because the official account is used for external events for our organization. And this is happening for internal meetings. [image: case of duplicate events]

Answer (score 7):

##### Not Duplicates

Strictly speaking, this is not a case of duplicate events in your calendar.  Rather, you are looking at 2 different Google users' calendars who are attending the same event.  Google helpfully layers the two calendars so you can see events from both at the same time.

This distinction is important as it explains why Google won't simply delete one of the events to make things more visually appealing.

If  **Account 1** is your primary Google account. The calendar for **Account 2** has permissions set to share it with **Account 1**.  Google won't remove events from **Account 2**'s calendar simply because **Account 1** is also an attendee (or vice versa).

#### So what can be done?

All that aside, your visual preference is not uncommon.  Automatically modifying the calendars is a non-starter, however in the case of calendars being viewing via Google Chrome for desktops (as opposed to on Android/iPhone), there is an extension that will visually blend the events together. I have been using it for several years without any hiccups.

**Event Merge** for Google Calendar ([chrome.google.com/webstore link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/event-merge-for-google-ca/idehaflielbgpaokehlhidbjlehlfcep?hl=en)) is a Chrome extension that **visually** merges the same event on multiple Google Calendars into one event.

It is also available on Github as **Google Multi-Calendar Event Merge** ([imightbeamy/gcal-multical-event-merge](https://github.com/imightbeamy/gcal-multical-event-merge)) for Chrome, FireFox or Greasemonkey.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately, the add-on has not been updated for 5 years and the repository seems to be abandoned by its creator. It does not work (properly) anymore, in Edge/Tampermonkey at least. There are some forks but they do not work for me either.

Comment: Still going strong for me in Chrome with the original extension.

Comment: Yep - Event Merge extension seems to work great - I'm on Arc browser and it works there too.

Answer (score -1):

i had this with holidays i had imported as events and they kept duplicating themselves (or however you want to define it). i discovered that in thunderbird (perhaps in outlook too) where i had subscribed to my google calendar, i could do a search for all "name-your-religion religious holidays" and simply select/delete all. i then went back into google (and thunderbird) and simply ADDED/subscribed-to THAT CALENDAR

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! We appreciate your participation & hope you'll continue to ask & answer & help others.  Please consider taking the quick [Tour] & reviewing [answer]. Note that your answer doesn't address the question which is about hiding the **same** event that shows in two calendars. The definition of "duplicate" in the context of the question matters (*"however you want to define it"*) if the event is deleted from the individual calendar they will no longer be an attendee. If it's deleted from the office calendar the event would be canceled & also deleted from all other calendars.